# Rename files in directory with first 8 characters and keep file extensions (Python)

Tags: python, file, directory, rename

I have a directory with 1000 files, all of the files start with an 8 digit unique identifier, for example `12345678-foo.txt`.

I'd rather not manually edit all 1000 files and have tried to write some Python code to do this for me:

```
for filename in os.listdir("C:/Users/me/Data/test"):
    extension = filename[-4:]
    os.rename(filename, filename[:8] + extension)
```

**This works on the first 6 or so files then I get the following error:**

```
WindowsError: [Error 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists
```

None of the files have duplicate names since the first 8 characters are unique.

Answer (score 3):

`filename[:7]` grabs the first 7 characters, not 8.

Comment: Thanks for catching that :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the file exists first and then try and rename a file if the new file name does not exist already. You can do this with:

```
os.path.isfile()
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile

So it would look something like this:

```
# get the directory of existing files
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname("C:/Users/me/Data/test")

# where we want to put the files when they are renamed
NEW_DIR = "./"

for filename in os.listdir(BASE_DIR):
    extension = filename[-4:]

    # add the extension and add the new path to the file
    new_file_name = filename[:8] + extension
    new_file_name = os.path.join(NEW_DIR, new_file_name)

    # check if the file exists before trying to rename
    if not os.path.isfile(new_file_name):
        print(new_file_name)
        os.rename(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, filename), new_file_name)
    else:
        print("file already exists: " + new_file_name)
```

Note: This allows you run the script from any directory and copy to any other directory by just changing the variables

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't the actual point of the question. The point of the question was how to fix the error: "WindowsError: [Error 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists".

Comment: I was under the impression that the issue was related to an incorrect string slice... hang on i'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks Dan, it worked for various directories but not for the files in the directory. I'll keep playing with it and see if I can get it working.